# Show that any ball (open or closed) in $\mathbb{R}^n$ is a convex set.

Tags: analysis

I tried to show that the set $X = \{(x, y)\in \mathbb{R}^2 : x^2 + y^2<1\}$ is convex.

Comment: So? How did you start?

Comment: Do you mean $x^2+y^2<1$? Because $(1,1), (-1,-1)\in X$ but the line connecting them is not.

Comment: really, I realized that it does not make sense what I wrote, I have no idea where to start.

Comment: I'm hopeless in this demonstration. Could someone help?